# Can I create a line graph from an Array?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, charts, series

I have 6 arrays of data as `longs`. I want to find a way to graph all six arrays as separate lines on a `Chart Control`.

I have created the `Chart` object, in my `Series Collection Editor` I have 6 members, but I cannot find a function that does something along the lines of `chart1.series1.setData(myArray)`.

I know I can go through and call `.add()` on every point, but I am wondering if there is a direct way to assign an array to a `Series`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built in way to add a whole range apart from databinding. You can call, as you said, the `AddXY` method of the `Points` property (or one of the related methods in the type `DataPointCollection`) of the Series, like so:

```
'Add data from Array1 to the first series of the chart
Chart.Series(0).Points.Clear() 'Clear all points
For i = 0 to Array1.Count - 1
   Chart.Series(0).Points.AddXY(i, Array1(i)) 'Adds the data from the array to the first series
Next
```

If you have the data in a multidimensional (e.g. `Dim Data()() As Long`) you can do something like

```
For a = 0 to Data.Count - 1
   Chart.Series(a).Points.Clear() 'Clear all points from the ath series
   For i = 0 to Data(a).Count - 1
      Chart.Series(a).Points.AddXY(i, Data(a)(i)) 'Adds the data from the ath array to the ath series
   Next      
Next
```

Note the X values will be just an index (0 to the array's count - 1) since you provided no further information.

Or you could write an extension method in a new `Module`

```
Public Module Extensions
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>
    Public Sub AddRange(d As System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPointCollection, data() As Long)
        Dim meCount As Integer = d.Count
        For i = 0 To data.Count - 1
            d.AddXY(meCount + i, data(i))
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```

Now you can just call the `AddRange` method for the `Points` property of the series:

```
Chart.Series(0).Points.AddRange(Array1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by adding point by point as Jens mentions, and this works find. Another way which should work fine is:

```
For a as integer = 0 to AmountOfSeries.count - 1 step 1
    Chart1.Series(a).Points.DataBindXY(ArrayX1, ArrayY1)
Next
```

This may be closer to what you were looking for - a way to set two arrays to a series.

Here's what it would look like with only one series:

```
Dim xs As Double() = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
Dim ys As Double() = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
Chart1.Series(0).Points.DataBindXY(xs, ys)
```